# Granting privilige in postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I am absolutely new to postgresSQL database. Using PhpPgAdmin, I was able to create database, user and a table. I am trying to insert a row into the table in my php file with the following codes:

```
$db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials" );
if($db){
  $psql = "INSERT INTO LOGINS (mid, name,ip,date) VALUES ($usid,'$naam','$ipad','$dte')";
  $ret = pg_query($db, $psql);
  $tot = pg_affected_rows($ret);
}
```

I am getting the error:
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: permission denied for relation..

I understand that some privileges are to be declared, but where and how?

Answer (score 1):

Use [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) to give privileges to users in Postgres

Comment: And there is also [DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) to avoid granting everything item by item.